# Pandas apply function returns None on Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

In my dataset I have columns of a pandas Timestamp, when I use apply to perform a conditional pandas returns None. Within the function that's returning the data(function name=get_start_times()) I am printing out each row which successfully prints the data and the type it is, so I know the data is there and the datatype is valid. I added a snippet of what the dataset looks like below and the function get_start_times code is below. Any help would be appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtJiD.png)

```
df["shift_start_time"] = df.apply(lambda x: get_start_times(x), axis=1)

def get_start_times(x: pd.Series):
    if 0 <= x["site_time"].hour <= 6:
        return x['shift_start_time'] - pd.Timedelta(days=1)
    elif x["shift_start_time"].hour <= x["site_time"].hour <= 23:
        return x["shift_start_time"]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I want to do simple correction. You can do it like that

```py
def get_start_times(x: pd.Series):
    if 0 <= x["site_time"].hour <= 6:
        return x['shift_start_time'] - pd.Timedelta(days=1)
    elif x["shift_start_time"].hour <= x["site_time"].hour <= 23:
        return x["shift_start_time"]

df["shift_start_time"] = df.apply(get_start_time, axis=1)
```

about the problem, I can't see any issue but one you have `if` and `elif` but when I checked your picture of data none of the conditions are true so none of the condition was met in your statemnets, So it is returning nothing. In order to check that can you add `else` statement there? for example:

```py
def get_start_times(x: pd.Series):
    if 0 <= x["site_time"].hour <= 6:
        return x['shift_start_time'] - pd.Timedelta(days=1)
    elif x["shift_start_time"].hour <= x["site_time"].hour <= 23:
        return x["shift_start_time"]
    else:
        # return anything that will tell you that this condition was met
```

hope this will help

Comment: @PandasM, you are welcome. let me know if it will help you.

Comment: It did. I have been messing around with it around midnight and day time, sometimes it would show the data then sometimes would show NaT or None, but now I see why. I simply overlooked the if statement part of it.

Comment: @PandasM nice to hear that. If it helped you. can you solve it as a solution if you are not against it? Thanks